# Flash + AS2 = Unload a movieclip itself when it is clicked

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs4, movieclip

I have a movieclip which unloads two other movieclips when it is clicked. This bit works fine, but it should also remove itself after this, which particularly does not work. Here is my code, can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong:

```
close_button.onRelease = function() {
 background.unloadMovie();
 loading.unloadMovie();
 this.unloadMovie();
}
```

Regards and TIA

// edit

Here is the code I create the movieclips:

```
// load background, movieclip container (loading) and close button
var background:MovieClip = _root.attachMovie("mc_back","loading_background", 100000);
var loading:MovieClip = _root.createEmptyMovieClip("loading",_root.getNextHighestDepth());
var close_button:MovieClip = _root.attachMovie("close_button","close_button",_root.getNextHighestDepth());
```

I tried:

`this._parent.close_button.unloadMovie(); // it removed the whole _root movieclip, as _root is the parent`

and

`_parent.close_button.unloadMovie(); // did just nothing`

Both failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event handler, '`this`' would refer to close_button, not the main movie.  All you need to do is either declare a variable equal to `this` outside of the close button onRelease handler, or try `this.parent.unloadMovie()` (assuming the parent of the close button is the movie you're trying to remove).

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it did not work, instead it unloaded everything in the swf, which was to be expected. Extra information in the post.

Answer (score 1):

a movieclip can not unload it's self because it cannot read a code that is not there so
it does not unload in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
close_button.onRelease = function() {
    background.unloadMovie();
    loading.unloadMovie();

    this.removeMovieClip();  // This 'removes' the movie clip
                             // which is the closest to 'unload'

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it did not work. Extra information in the question.

Comment: So you mean you want to unload the button? The button can't be unloaded but just hidden. I'm updating the answer